# Composing same two functions and merge results in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a function which has this type:

```
Function<String,List<String>> generate
```

Currently I'm using like this:

```
List<String> a1 = generate.apply("");
List<String> a2 = generate.apply("");
List<String> a3 = generate.apply("");
List<String> all = new ArrayList<>();
a1.addAll(a2);
a1.addAll(a3);
all.addAll(a1);
```

Is there any way I can compose the same function and expect all its results(`List<String>`) to be merged?

How can I do that in Java 8?

Comment: So you are applying the same function three times with the same arguments, right? Does it always return different result? Or in your code actually arguments are different? Or you have several different functions like `generate1`, `generate2`, etc.? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use the `Stream::flatMap` method kind of the other way of what Yassin Hajaj did:

```
List<String> all = 
    Stream.of("", "", "")
          .flatMap(generate.andThen(List::stream))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `Stream#flatMap`.

Stream over all your collections and collect each one of the indexes into one big List.

```
List<String> merged = Stream.of(a1, a2, a3)
                            .flatMap(x -> x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to **compose** two functions `f` ang `g` you can do `g.compose(f)`, or similarily `f.andThen(g)`. That only works if you have `Function<A,B> f` and `Function<B,C> g`. In other words, you need to make sure that `f` returns the same type as the input type of function `g`. Therefore you cannot compose `generate`with itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example use `FunctionInterface` with `Stream` Function:

```
Function<String, Stream<String>> generate = s -> Stream.of(s);
final List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");       


strs.stream().flatMap(generate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In the above code `flatMap`, it using the `generate` `Function` to `map`